# reformat file in bash

Tags: bash, perl, awk

A file I would like to parse looks like

```
#header
#header2
#header 3
# header


 1       565286  SNP1-555149     C       T       .       PASS    AC=4270AF=1.00;AN=4270;set=broad       GT      1/1   /1     1/1     1/1     1/1     1/1


1       534247  SNP1-524110     C       T       .       PASS    AC=36;AF=7.772e-03;AN=4632;set=Intersection     GT      0/0     0/0     0/0
```

There is a header - which shall be skipped. Afterwards I just need the first 3 field (they are tab delimted  like

```
1 565286 SNP1-555149
```

there are several lines in the field but only the first two after the header are shown...

Comment: @Serg  tried to read it into R but the file is to large 12 gb to efficiently parse it in R - am not proficient in bash

Comment: OK. Does the file have the same structure ? Is it always 1 line of data, then 4 lines of `1/1`  and `./.` ?

Comment: @Serg - it can be a number from 1 to 22 in the first - the lines seen above are in 1 line the newline character is after the last bit (that can be 1/1 as above) - so from the line it shall just get the first 4 fields...

Answer (score 0):

Tell awk to not match any line starting with `#` and whatever else till end of line; do not match empty lines; for lines that don't  have those patters, print fields 1,2 and 3 .

```
$> cat inputData.txt                                                           
    #header
    #header2
  #  header 3
   # header


 1       565286  SNP1-555149     C       T       .       PASS    AC=4270AF=1.00;AN=4270;set=broad       GT      1/1   /1     1/1     1/1     1/1     1/1


1       534247  SNP1-524110     C       T       .       PASS    AC=36;AF=7.772e-03;AN=4632;set=Intersection     GT      0/0     0/0     0/0     
$> awk '!/^#.+$/ && !/^$/ { print $1,$2,$3  } ' inputData.txt                  
1 565286 SNP1-555149
1 534247 SNP1-524110
```

Comment: sorry it is always #text in the header -sorry I edited that- does that change the solution

Comment: Almost doesn't change the solution. It just makes it even better :)

Comment: I made just a small edit. Changed `/\#.+$/` to `/^#.+$/` Now that should work perfectly